# words in an ordered list will not wrap when the input is too large

Tags: html, reactjs, word-wrap

My words are not wrapping when the input is too long. I have tried using flex-wrap and align-items but to no avail. As soon as the input it too large, it spills over. Here is how it looks below.
[image]

Here is my Css file

```
.recipe{ 
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px black;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background:white;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 40%;
    flex-wrap: 'wrap';
    white-space: unset;
}

.image{
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And here is my javascript file recipe.js

```
import React from "react";
import style from './recipe.module.css'

const Recipe = ({title, calories, image, ingredients}) => {

    const round = Math.round(calories);
    
   
    return(
        <div className = {style.recipe}>
            <h1 >{title}</h1>

            <ol>
                {ingredients.map(ingredient => (
                    <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
                ))}            
            </ol>

            <p>calories: {round} </p>
            

            <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/>

           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recipe;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ingredients' parent element is not the div, it's `<ol>` tag. so you need to make that flex , then you can use flex-wrap, or you proably won't need.

Answer (score 1):

Two things if you want an element's text to wrap:

1. their container element must have a limited width (but right now your OL lacks one, and is exceeding the width of its parent)
2. the element with the text to be wrapped should have a style of `whitespace: wrap` (but currently it doesn't ... or at least not an explicit one, but it's likely the default value already)